# synology cross compile gcc -std=c++0x

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm willing to compile a program that needs -std=c++0x option of gcc to make it execute Synology x86 NAS system (Intel Atom). I'm using the cross-compiling toolchain (synoroot directory).

```
$cat tst.cpp
tst.cpp:
    int main() {
    return 0;
}

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2

$gcc tst.cpp -std=c++0x --sysroot=/usr/local/synoroot -nodefaultlibs /usr/local/synoroot/lib/libc.so /usr/local/synoroot/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /usr/local/synoroot/usr/lib/libstdc++.so /usr/local/synoroot/lib/libm.so -o tst

$./tst && echo $?
0
```

On synology:

```
$./tst
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

If I use the toolchain gcc (i686-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 4.2.1), ./tst executes correctly on synology but the -std=c++0x is not supported.

So how can I have successful execution and C++0x support ?

Cheers

Comment: by using a gcc version that supports c++11 :)

Comment: You would have to get a cross compiling build with a newer GCC version.

Answer (score 1):

If you target system (Synology) differs sufficiently from your host system(Ubuntu) to need a cross-compiler, then you only have two options:

1. Get a newer cross-compilation toolchain that supports the new language/library features that you need (possibly building it yourself from source)
2. Rewrite the application such that it does not need the C++0x features.

Comment: 1. As far as I know, the toolchain I use is the most "recent" one (gcc from 'O7 ... I know) provided by synology or others (spksrc)

Comment: 2. Rewriting the project is not even a viable solution (it is really huge) :)

Comment: @user1970105: The current toolchain might be the latest pre-compiled version, but if you get the GCC (and standard library) 4.7 sources, you will be able to build your own v4.7 cross-compiler

Answer (score 0):

If you just like to run or compile and run on your synology, you can choose Debian Chroot your DSM.With this, you can do everything you want on your synology.

Here is my Debian-Chroot.pkg for DSM6.x repo, you can install with it.
https://github.com/OKit-Scripts-Projects/DSM.Customizations/blob/master/App.Debian-Chroot.md

Any problem, feel free to comment or open a issue.